# How to install GitLab on Ubuntu 16.04 with an existing Apache installation

Tags: 16.04, apache2, gitlab

I'd be really grateful if anyone could share the magic needed (ideally in precisely detailed steps!) to get GitLab running on Ubuntu 16.04 with an existing and working Apache2 and iRedMail/PostgreSQL installation.

I started with the answer for [14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698346/gitlab-apache-ubuntu-14-04) and then followed up with the 'not responding' [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816046/gitlab-is-not-responding-502-on-ubuntu-14-04-after-starting-server?rq=1).

Whichever way around I set the gitlab.rb external_url and the Apache2 rules Unicorn kept complaining the listener port was in use ...

Many thanks.

Comment: For anyone else trying to do this: don't. Install the marvellous gogs instead: https://gogs.io/

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to stop using bundled nginx server and point new port[8080 or any other] to your gitlab web directory. Below link might help:

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/solved-setting-up-gitlab-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-apache2-without-owning-a-domain-name/679/8